# Web Site Security - 1 main site, 1 secondary site hosted within the main site

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, security, web, razor-pages

Scenario:

ASP.NET 5 / Razor Pages / C#

We have one main site, with very good security. In the background, all passwords are encrypted. Also, a log is made of all logon usernames, from which IP addresses, at whatever time accessed.

We have a second site that is hosted within the main site visually on the front end via iframes mostly, but not on the server. They won't live together in the same web app.

Problem:

I need to ensure that the secondary site access is secure, whilst relying on the fact that the user already logged on successfully via the main website. I don't want the user to need to logon twice to two systems, rather I want the single logon to fluidly allow access to the secondary site.

I have a method I am using now. It works, but I really want to delve in and see if I can improve this given I'm not heavy on experience in terms of website security. I'm sure there is a better way.

Options?

Answer (score 1):

From a security point of view, using iframes, the two site are independent.
So you need to guarantee that the security process is issued on both sides.

You have several possibilities, but the best, I think, is to revalidate the user in the "iframed" website.

You can use a token, generated from the main website and stored in a backend DB, and pass it to the iframe URL.
The endpoint of the iframe has to read the token, call a backend API to validate it and allow the access.

The main problem you have is to refresh the token after a reasonable time, in order to ensure the validity during the use of the "iframed" website.

Comment: Interesting. This is good food for thought. I will make note, and await further answers too.